# Formatar csv via php

Tags: php, csv

tenho o seguinte codigo, onde ele gera uma planilha csv.

```
<?php
    require_once ('dbacess.php');
    // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

    // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    // output the column headings

    // fetch the data

    $rows = sprintf('select * from ivr_contatos, ivr_campanha,ivr_business where ivr_contatos.campanha = ivr_campanha.id and ivr_business.idvisita = ivr_contatos.codigo and ivr_contatos.status = 0 and tentativas >= qtdtentativas');
    $linha = Populator::ConsultaDB($rows);
    // loop over the rows, outputting them
    fputcsv($output,array("CHAMADO","NOME","TELEFONE","TENTATIVA","DATA"));
    while ($resultado = pg_fetch_array($linha) ) {
        $chamado = $resultado['numerochamado'];
        $nome = $resultado['nome'];
        $telefone = $resultado['telefone'];
        $tentativa = $resultado['tentativas'];
        $lastAttempt = $resultado['atualizado'];
        $dataconvertida = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($lastAttempt));
        $codigo = $resultado['codigo'];    
        fputcsv($output,array($chamado.";".$nome.";".$telefone.";".$tentativa.";".$dataconvertida));
    }
?>
```

Ele esta funcional, entretanto queria que cada dado ficasse em uma célula, invés de todos estarem na célula A, existe alternativa a isso?

Comment: vc diz que o ultimo fputcsv esta colocando os dados em uma unica celula, no caso a celula CHAMADO, isso?

Comment: Isso, eu gostaria que o que fosse correspondente a chamado ficasse na celula A, o que fosse nome Celula B, inves de todos agrupados na celula A como esta ocorrendo

Comment: o nome dos campos estão separados? ou estão juntos tbm?

Comment: Você está agrupando o array com ".", esse é o problema. O fputcsv espera campos separados.

Comment: @wees estão juntos tambem

Comment: @Bacco, tabém achei que fosse, mas no primeiro array já esta salvando numa unica celula

Comment: @WeesSmith isso é por que ele não definiu o separador como ';' (o padrão é ',').

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seu erro está aqui, Você está concatentando tudo em uma string só:

```
fputcsv($output,array($chamado.";".$nome.";".$telefone.";".$tentativa.";".$dataconvertida));
```

**Maneira correta**:

```
//                     .--- Array de campos
fputcsv($output, array($chamado, $nome, $telefone, $tentativa, $dataconvertida), ';');
//       '--- handle do arquivo                                      separador ---'
```

O primeiro campo é o *handle*, o segundo o *array* de campos, o terceiro o separador. Não se esqueça de por o separador nos títulos também.

Manual:

> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Nesse formato, separando só por virgula, continua agrupado tudo na celular A ainda.

Comment: Isso é falta de você setar o separador.

Comment: Show de bola galera!

Comment: Eu também não tinha esse conhecimento, obrigado pelo aprendizado.

Comment: @WeesSmith estamos aí pra isso. Mas é importante sempre dar uma lida no manual. Muitas vezes tem funções corriqueiras com muitos detalhes que a gente nem imagina. Por mais experiência que eu tenha com PHP, eu estou sempre relendo. (isso vale pra todas as linguagens que eu uso - saber como usar é muito mais importante do que "decorar" a função). Recomento que as pessoas façam o mesmo, independente de experiência.

Comment: perfeito @Bacco ,realmente não tinha esse conhecimento, como era uma coisa corriqueira que nunca fiz antes, não tinha esse conhecimento.

Comment: Obrigado aos dois pelo auxilio

Comment: @WillianLima por um instante achei que vc tinha sumido, fiquei preocupado sem saber se tinha resolvido ou não kkk - tava até comentando no chat da rede. Tendo duvidas, pergunte (mas sempre leia o manual, ele é que pode te salvar em horários que nao tiver ninguem aqui pra responder) :)

Comment: @Bacco Sai para almoçar cara hahaha Foi descuido mesmo, eu tava fuçando alguns metodos de como resolver esse problema, mas nem passou pela cabeça o manual, serve de aprendizado agora haha Obrigado!

Comment: @Bacco eu sempre faço isso